# Android How to change icon with button

Tags: android, android-layout, button, view

This is my XML

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/w1"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="@color/buttons_background"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_more"
  android:fontFamily="roboto medium"
  android:paddingLeft="30dp"
  android:paddingRight="30dp"
  android:text="@string/w1_btn_more"
  android:textColor="@color/text_color"
  android:textSize="17sp" />
```

How to change from icon_more to icon_next.

Piece of code Java

```
Button w1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.w1);
w1.set("???");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.your_drwable);
img.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );
imgView.setCompoundDrawables( null, null, img, null );
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
w1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.next, 0);
```

to change the `android:drawableRight` property programmatically. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) the documentation

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`to set respective drawable at run time :

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left,int top,int right,int bottom);
```

In your case :

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.icon_next,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a drawableRight, you might want to use this

```
w1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.icon_next, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon_next);
```

img.setBounds( 60, 60, 0, 0 );
txtVw.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
w1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_next);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
w1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_next);
```